# Concatenating 2 arrays without memcpy

Tags: c, dynamic-arrays

Suppose I ve

```
int *a,*b;  
a= malloc(5*sizeof(int));  
b= malloc(5*sizeof(int));
```

and subsequently assign values.

Let a - 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
    b - 6, 7, 8, 9, 10

Is there a method to concatenate both these malloced arrays **without using further `malloc`,`realloc` or `memcpy`**? There shud not be a malloc of 10 locations!

I must be able to get `a[8]=9` after executing, without the overhead of moving the arrays.
**The language is C**

Comment: Your question is meaningless. If you want to allocate 10 adjacent cells, why aren't you doing exactly that?

Comment: @EJP This is a simplified form of my prob. I ve task of combining 2 sets of data whose sizes are guided by some other factors.

Comment: Your question remains meaningless. `malloc()` allocates a new block of memory. A 2nd `malloc()` allocates another one. If you want them to be contiguous, allocate them both at the same time. There is no other answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't need strict array indexing, you could make a pseudo-linked-list (I know there's a name for this data type but I can't remember it right now):

```
struct listish {
  int *arr
  size_t size;
  struct listish *next;
};
```

The "indexing" function would look like this:

```
int *index(struct listish *list, size_t i)
{
    if(list == NULL) return NULL; // index out of bounds
    if(i < list->size) return list->arr + i; // return a pointer to the element
    else return index(list->next, i - list->size); // not in this array - go to next node
}
```

The idea is to combine the in-place reordering of a linked list with the contiguous space of an array. In this case, `index(list, 4)` would return `&a[4]`, and `index(list, 5)` would return `&b[0]`, simulating continuous indexing without reallocating and moving your entire array - all you need to do is allocate a few small `struct listish` objects and set them up properly, a task I leave to you.

Comment: @tss - If you want more info, the name of this data structure appears to be an [unrolled linked list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unrolled_linked_list), though this is a slight variation that uses externally-managed arrays. Still, same concept.

Answer (score 6):

> ```
> a= malloc(5*sizeof(int));
> ```

You only allocated 5 ints to a, so no, you can't do it without some form or memory allocation (`malloc` / `realloc`), since **`a[8]` would be illegal** to begin with.

> I must be able to get a[8]=9 after executing, without the overhead of
>   moving the arrays

Since since you are working with contiguous memory regions (which you are calling arrays) **you will always have some overhead when moving elements around**. If you don't need to access elements by their indexes just use linked lists.

Comment: By overhead I mean, doing a malloc of 10 locations, copying the elements from a and b and subsequently freeing the initial locations.

Answer (score 2):

What you ask can't be done.

You have, maybe, another option.
Just allocate space for 10 values, and make `b` point to the correct element

```
int *a = malloc(10 * sizeof *a);
/* error checking missing */
int *b = a + 5;

a[0] = 1; a[1] = 2; a[2] = 3; a[3] = 4; a[4] = 5;
b[0] = 6; b[1] = 7; b[2] = 8; b[3] = 9; b[4] = 10;

printf("a[8] is %d\n", a[8]);
```